# Casting Long to Integer inside function

Tags: clojure, casting, long-integer

I am writing a function that converts three numbers (r,g,b) into a single integer that is used by `java.awt.Color`

```
(defn to-rgb
  ([r g b] (bit-or
            (long 4278190080) ; the alpha channel = (bit-shift-left 255 24)
            (bit-shift-left r 16)
            (bit-shift-left g 8)
            b)))
```

Using the `Color` constructor and `.getRGB`

```
bitmap> (.getRGB (Color. 0 0 0))
-16777216
bitmap> (type (.getRGB (Color. 0 0 0)))
java.lang.Integer
(Integer/toBinaryString (.getRGB (Color. 0 0 0)))
"11111111000000000000000000000000"
```

And then my version. So I need to cast to an `Integer`

```
bitmap> (to-rgb 0 0 0)
4278190080
bitmap> (Integer. (to-rgb 0 0 0))
-16777216 ; as expected
```

So I decided to put the cast inside the function as I always want an Integer returned.

```
(defn to-rgb2
  ([r g b] (Integer. (bit-or
                      (long 4278190080)
                      (bit-shift-left r 16)
                      (bit-shift-left g 8)
                      b))))

bitmap> (to-rgb2 0 0 0)
IllegalArgumentException Value out of range for int: 4278190080  clojure.lang.RT.intCast (RT.java:1205)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, an `Integer` is only 32 bits. Change it to `Long`:

```
(Long. ...)
```

The problem is the constant `4278190080` translates to `0xFF000000` in hex, where we see that the left-most bit is set.  In Java, since integer values are signed 32-bit, the left-most bit cannot be set as it is reserved for negative numbers in two's-compliment notation.

```
java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE = 0x7FFFFFFF
```

in hex.

---

**Update**

If you need it as a 32-bit value, use `Long.intValue()` like so:

```
(defn to-rgb3
  ([r g b] (.intValue
             (Long. (bit-or
                      (long 4278190080)
                      (bit-shift-left r 16)
                      (bit-shift-left g 8)
                      b)))))
(dotest
  (spyxx (to-rgb3 0 0 0)))

(to-rgb3 0 0 0) => java.lang.Integer->-16777216
```

Comment: but I need the value `-16777216` which comes from casting the long to an integer. It should match the return value of `(.getRGB (Color. 0 0 0))`

Comment: I think my edit makes it clearer no? My question is why does a cast *work* (yes it converts to neg) outside of a function but not inside?

Comment: `.intValue` was what I was looking for :)

Comment: Note that `.intValue` returns a primivite Java `int`, which Clojure then auto-boxes into an `Integer` object.

Comment: `Number.intValue` is expressed more idiomatically in pure Clojure as `unchecked-int`.